# What's the point of hibernatetemplate's bulkupdate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Is hibernatetemplate's `bulkUpdate` actually doing a `bulkUpdate`? I looked at the code, and it doesn't seem to be doing `bulkUpdate`. Or maybe am I missing something?

```
public int bulkUpdate(final String queryString, final Object... values) throws DataAccessException {
        return executeWithNativeSession(new HibernateCallback<Integer>() {
            public Integer doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
                Query queryObject = session.createQuery(queryString);
                prepareQuery(queryObject);
                if (values != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                        queryObject.setParameter(i, values[i]);
                    }
                }
                return queryObject.executeUpdate();
            }
        });
    }
```

whereas `JdbcTemplate batchUpdate` (looks like) is doing a `batchUpdate`

```
public int[] batchUpdate(final String[] sql) throws DataAccessException {
        Assert.notEmpty(sql, "SQL array must not be empty");
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Executing SQL batch update of " + sql.length + " statements");
        }
        class BatchUpdateStatementCallback implements StatementCallback<int[]>, SqlProvider {
            private String currSql;
            public int[] doInStatement(Statement stmt) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                int[] rowsAffected = new int[sql.length];
                if (JdbcUtils.supportsBatchUpdates(stmt.getConnection())) {
                    for (String sqlStmt : sql) {
                        this.currSql = sqlStmt;
                        stmt.addBatch(sqlStmt);
                    }
                    rowsAffected = stmt.executeBatch();
                }
                else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < sql.length; i++) {
                        this.currSql = sql[i];
                        if (!stmt.execute(sql[i])) {
                            rowsAffected[i] = stmt.getUpdateCount();
                        }
                        else {
                            throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException("Invalid batch SQL statement: " + sql[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return rowsAffected;
            }
            public String getSql() {
                return this.currSql;
            }
        }
        return execute(new BatchUpdateStatementCallback());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is doing bulk update. As you see, `DELETE` and `INSERT` queries executed in `bulkUpdate` method *can* affect multiple rows. That's why they are called bulk operations.

Point is to have handy method to execute update and execute query and return number of rows affected in bulk operation. Additionally it wraps exceptions to DataAccessException.